# React onChange Method not changing state of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react-date-picker, I want to create it as a date picker component which I can use on every part of my pages. The onchange method is where I have a problem with because at the time of state change,it doesn't know the column it is changing. I am missing something in the onchange method. When I choose a date,the error is get is The state is always empty.This is the results in my console.

> 21/12/2018

```
export class DatePickerNew extends React.PureComponent<IIDateTimeProps, any> 
{
    classes: string[];
    constructor(props: IIDateTimeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dirty: false,
            valid: false,
            validated: false,
            maxLength: this.props.maxLength || 250,
            minLength: this.props.minLength || 1,
            minNumber: this.props.minNumber || 0,
            maxNumber: this.props.maxNumber || 999999999999999,
            type: "date",
            validationMessage: "",
            selected:""

        } 
    }
    onChange = date => {
        const result = Validation.inputValidation(date, this.state);
        //date = DateTime.parse(date, DateTime.dateOutPutFormat);
        this.setState({
            validated: true,
            valid: result.state,
            dirty: true,
          selected: moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY').toString(),
          value:this.state.selected

        });
        console.log(this.state.value)
        console.log(this.state.selected)
      };

render() {
        this.classes = this.props.classes || [];

        return (
            <ErrorBoundary errorMessage="Error rendering DatePicker">

                  <DatePick

                    id={this.props.id}
                    name={this.props.name}
                    title={this.props.title}  
                    required={this.props.required}

                    value={this.state.selected}
                    onChange={this.onChange}

                    peekNextMonth
                    showMonthDropdown
                    showYearDropdown
                    dropdownMode="select"
                    type="text"
                    placeholderText="DD/MM/YYYY"
                    />


            </ErrorBoundary>);
    }
}
```

This is how I call it in another component

```
<DatePickerNew 
id="holidayDate" 
title="Holiday Date" 
label="Holiday Date"
type="text"
required={true} 
name="holidayDate"
isClearable={true}

/>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to pass parameters to the function you have to bind or call a callback function!

onChange={this.onChange} //Wrong way

The solution is:

```
onChange={() => this.onChange(date)} //The most used way!
```

or

```
onChange={this.onChange.bind(this,date)}
```

One of them should work for you !

Comment: That didn't work as well,it keeps telling me it expects only 1 arguement but I have provided 2

Answer (score 0):

Did you bind the onChange method in your constructor? Like so:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}
```

I stripped out some of the other stuff to just focus on the event binding. Here's also a bigger breakdown of forms and such through their documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

*Also, this is super nitpicky, but handleChange would be more semantic than onChange for this type of situation.*

Comment: I have but it still has no state